# Rest Query Managed Metadata Filter

Tags: javascript, managed-metadata, rest, client-object-model

I am currently writing a JSON query for office 365 (sharepoint 2013) where the filter is suppose to filter depending on values returned from a managed metadata field

I am trying to filter based on status field equal to a certain value. Status is the managed metadata column so how do I write this in the filter

The filter currently has no criteria therefore reads as follows :

```
https://site collection/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?  $select=Title,AuthorId,,LastReplyById,DiscussionLastUpdated,Modified,Status, Created&$filter= "WHAT DO I PLACE HERE TO FILTER BY STATUS".
```

See the picture of what the returned data is.

[image]

I need to know what the filter will be for the status field.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to use a $filter= and specify a managed metadata field - this is not supported by SharePoint. The only way to filter a REST query using a managed metadata field is to use a CAML query, which requires a POST, not a GET.

Since you mention JSON, I assume you are developing it in Javascript. This is a small snippet of code to get you started:

```
var taxoField = "Status";
var taxoValue = "Completed";
restUrl = appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" +
            "{\"ViewXml\":\"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef%20Name='" +
            taxoField + "'/><Value%20Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>" + taxoValue + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>\"}" +
            select;
$.ajax(
    {
        url: restUrl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    }
);
```

The appWebUrl, is your site URL such as https://contoso.sharepoint.com. The CAML query is built using 2 variables taxoField (name of the field), and taxoValue (value to look for). Note that the AJAX call uses the POST method (required to execute a CAML query), and the header then must have an X-RequestDigest.

You should put error checking in the AJAX call, but it is pretty close to this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great post...does this work on a managed meta data field with "Allow Multiples" checked or only single values? I need to check if the any of the values contains a value.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but pretty confident that it also works with multi value metadata field.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Pierrebo, $filter does not support Managed Metadata Column(MMC) in REST API - GET method, I have tested below code with REST API POST Method & used for getting the filtered row count.

- Set the listname, MMD column name, MMD column value
  var listName  = "Custom_TaskList"
  var taxoField = "Status";
  var taxoValue = "Completed";
  GetTaxanomyItemsLength(listName, taxoField, taxoValue);
- Helper function to retrieve filtered value

  ```
  function GetTaxanomyItemsLength(listName, taxoField, taxoValue)
  {
   $.ajax({  
  url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/lists/getByTitle('" + listName + "')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef%20Name='"+ taxoField + "'/><Value%20Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>" + taxoValue + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"}",  
  type: type,  
  data: data,  
  headers:  
  {  
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
      "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),              
      "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"   
  },  
  cache: false,  
  success: function(data)   
  {  
     alert("Success"+data.d.results.length);
  },  
  error: function(data)  
  {  
      console.log(data.responseJSON.error);  
  }  
  });  
  }
  ```