# GET SharePoint Managed Metadata Field with REST API Giving Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, managed-metadata

I am trying to retrieve a Managed Metadata column from a SharePoint list using a REST call. The column/field name is Department. I found this site, https://threewill.com/pulling-managed-metadata-values-via-rest/ and I tried the query with TaxCatchAll, but it gives me the below error:

"The field 'TaxCatchAll' is not supported in query. The lookup list is in another web."

`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=*,TaxCatchAll/Department&$filter=TaxCatchAll/Department eq 'ListName'&$expand=TaxCatchAll";`

That is the only source I can find, is there another way to go about this or is it not possible to GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving TaxCatchAll column can help us get metadata id and term label.

Try to use this:

```
  _api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=Department,TaxCatchAll/ID,TaxCatchAll/Term&$filter=Department eq 'ListName'&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

Comment: I get an error message with a managed metadata field: The field 'Department' of type 'TaxonomyFieldType' cannot be used in the query filter expression. Thoughts?

Comment: You can refer to this question:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98827/rest-query-managed-metadata-filter