# How to count SharePoint list from managed metadata column in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts

I have one field manage metadata which name is department and its has 3 value HR, Admin and account so I want to filter out Admin data and display count of results. I am using SharePoint online.

Comment: Hi @vinia, did you try my solution given below? Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes working but  i want also looking for all manage metadata list fields

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one managed metadata column in your SharePoint list, you can use API call like:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EInfochips')/items?$filter=TaxCatchAll/Term eq 'Admin'
```

**Source**: [Filter a SharePoint list on a Managed Metadata field in a REST based client application](https://itgeneralisten.wordpress.com/2018/10/09/filter-a-sharepoint-list-on-a-managed-metadata-field-in-a-rest-based-client-application/)

---

Also, you can get the list items based on managed metadata column filter using `POST` API call and CAML query like:

```
var listName = "EInfochips";
var taxoField = "Department";
var taxoValue = "Admin";
restUrl = appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" +
            "{\"ViewXml\":\"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef%20Name='" +
            taxoField + "'/><Value%20Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>" + taxoValue + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>\"}" +
            select;
$.ajax(
    {
        url: restUrl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    }
);
```

**Source**: [Rest Query Managed Metadata Filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98827/rest-query-managed-metadata-filter)

Where `Department` is internal name of your managed metadata column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Once you get the array of results back from API call, you can get the count of returned results by using `.length` property or array like:

```
console.log("No. of results: " + dataresults.length);
```